# Leaving blank arguments in a new command

Tags: arguments, renewcommand

If I am using this simple new command...

```
\newcommand{\Lem}[3]{
\begin{lemma}
{#1}
\begin{itemize}
\item{#2}
\item{#3}
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}
}
```

how can I use it if for example I only have one item in the list part. Thanks

Comment: note item does not take an argument so `\item #2` not `\item{#2}` also take care to use `%` at ends of lines to avoid adding extra white space.

Comment: Please always include a complete MWE. Don't make other users do more work. Start with `\documentclass`, include all relevant `\usepackage` commands, and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need *some* syntax to separate the items, you could use `{..}{...}` or (if there are no commas in the items `{... , ... , ...}` but I would use the standard latex syntax  `\item ... \item ...`  then you just need

```
\newcommand{\Lem}[2]{%<<<
\begin{lemma}%<--
{#1}%
\begin{itemize}
#2
\end{itemize}%<
\end{lemma}%<
}

\Lem{foo}{\item this  \item that}
```

---

Although generally I'd avoid hiding environments in commands, environments are a core part of latex syntax and you can get better context syntax help, and more functionality, eg use of `\verb` or `minted` if you use an environment.

```
\newenvironment{\Lem}[]{%<<<
\begin{lemma}%<--
{#1}%
\begin{itemize}%
}
{%
\end{itemize}%<
\end{lemma}%<
}

\begin{Lem}{foo}
\item this
\item that
\end{Lem}
```

Answer (score 5):

The command `\Lem` is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`. The first argument is mandatory. The second till ninth argument are optional. It uses `\IfValueT` to test if an argument is empty.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lem}{moooooooo}{\begin{lemma}
#1
\IfValueT{#2}{\begin{itemize}
\IfValueT{#2}{\item #2}
\IfValueT{#3}{\item #3}
\IfValueT{#4}{\item #4}
\IfValueT{#5}{\item #5}
\IfValueT{#6}{\item #6}
\IfValueT{#7}{\item #7}
\IfValueT{#8}{\item #8}
\IfValueT{#9}{\item #9}
\end{itemize}}\end{lemma}}
\begin{document}
\Lem{Example 1} end
\Lem{Example 2}[item 1] end
\Lem{Example 3}[item 1][item 2][item 3][item 4] end
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place the items in a loop, for example using `\foreach` from the `pgffor` package (included in `tikz` if you're using that). Note that if an item includes commas you must enclose it in braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand{\Lem}[2]{
    \begin{lemma}{#1}
        \begin{itemize}
            \foreach \i in {#2}
                {\item \i}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{lemma}
}

\begin{document}

\Lem{Here is a lemma.}{Item.}
\Lem{Here is another lemma.}{Item 1., Item 2., {Items 3, 4, 5.}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A version closer to the original code, that checks if `#3` is empty. In that case nothing is done, in the `\else` case an `\item` is added for the argument. This requires that the argument is always provided (`\Lem{Here is a lemma.}{Item.}{}` for example), unlike the [anwer from matexmatics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707581/) which uses actual optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand{\Lem}[3]{
    \begin{lemma}{#1}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item #2
            \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\else
               \item #3
            \fi
        \end{itemize}
    \end{lemma}
}

\begin{document}

\Lem{Here is a lemma.}{Item.}{}
\Lem{Here is another lemma.}{Item 1.}{Item 2.}

\end{document}
```